# svchost causing problems

Tags: windows-7, cpu, lag, svchost

Lately I've had one particular svchost.exe instance that's often spiking up and taking 12-40% of my CPU. The services it's hosting are:

- FDResPub (Function Discovery Resource Publication)
- FontCache (Windows Font Cache Service)
- SSDPSRV (SSDP Discovery)
- upnphost (UPnP Device Host)

This was causing major problems on my computer (which had been running for 25 days without restart), so I figured a reboot would fix it. Guessed wrong, it's taking 25% of CPU from the moment I logged in.

Can anyone provide any insight as to what might be causing this particular svchost to be so CPU-consuming? It's becoming a major hindrance since it's preventing me from running any other CPU-intensive process (namely games but other programs too)

If you need any more information from me, don't hesitate to ask :)
(Running Windows 7 Home Premium x86)

EDIT: Stopping FDResPub seems to have fixed the problem. I looked it up and it seems unlikely that I actually will ever want it running... Anyway, this makes sense since I'm on a huge network here and about 99% of the computers use Windows 7 and probably have homegroup features... I'm rambling here :D But if anyone has anything to add to this, please do so :)

Comment: have you tried manually halting those services one at a time to narrow down which one is behaving badly?

Comment: Yes I have - beat you to it ;)

Comment: assuming [this](http://wiki.blackviper.com/wiki/Function_Discovery_Resource_Publication) wiki is accurate it looks like the FDResPub service enables HomeGroup features as well as publishing of shared resources to the network (folders/drives/printers). as long as you can live without all that then you will probably be OK disabling it. if you *do* disable it keep an eye out after Windows Updates are installed as it may be set back to automatic start.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the warning about Windows Updates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact problem with the same four services except that it would happen sometimes for hour and then go away for hours. It went away when I disconnected from HomeGroup and I am about certain that it was my Xbox being on or off that caused the problem to occur intermittently.