# svchost causes high cpu usage

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, svchost

Svchost.exe in my Windows 7(x64, Ultimate) PC causes high CPU usage sometimes.
The CPU stays at about 65%. The services which are being run by this instance of svchost are **FDResPub**, **SSDPSRV** and **upnphost**.
I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/217279/svchost-causing-problems) question to be same with mine, but except for **FontCache** service, also I find it that the high CPU usage is only when I am connected to internet, if I disconnect it, the usage drops.
Is there any solution to this ?(*I just recovered from high usage of RAM by an instance of svchost*)

P.S: I do not use an Xbox

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the high CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and share the file

Comment: the 8.1 version of the WPT also works for Windows 7. Install it.

Comment: as I wrote in my paste, compress it as 7z (LZMA2/ULTRA) to reduce the size a lot.

Comment: ok, use the MSI from my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz1x4gvxl630qpo/WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi?dl=1

Comment: were you able to capture the trace? Is it possible for you to upload the compressed trace or is the file still too large?

Comment: the trace is too short. Run it as elast for 30s. Also only share the highCPUusage.etl, the kernel.etl is useless for me.

Comment: I only see a lot of cpu usage from USB Modem.exe and DWM.exe but not from Svchost.exe. you have to run the command when you see the issue  in taskmgr.

Comment: I will let you know when I come across the issue again and post a trace here

Answer (score 0):

Please see cluberti's reply here:

http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/284812-fdrespub-service-eats-cpu-resources.html

It sounds like something is misusing UPNP.